# Sum each column in SQL and show them in Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum, unpivot

I have a table 'task' like below
[image: task table]

where ID is unique record and deptA.....deptD are departments. 1 denotes completed and 0 incomplete.
I want to calculate sum of each department as below

[image: result]

I am trying to do like below but I don't know how to transpose to row

```
select Sum(deptA) as deptA, 
       Sum(deptB) as deptB, 
       Sum(deptC) as deptC, 
       Sum(deptD) as deptD, 
       count(*) as total 
  from task
```

Note - can't use pivot/unpivot function as my application doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unpivot with `cross apply`, and then aggregate:

```
select x.dept, sum(x.status) complete, sum(1 - x.status) incomplete
from task t
cross apply (values 
    ('deptA', deptA), ('deptB', deptB), ('deptC', deptC), ('deptD', deptD)
) x(dept, status)
group by x.dept
```

This assumes only `0`/`1` values in the departments columns, which simplifies the aggregation logic.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be `Conditional Aggregation` along with `UNION ALL` in order to unpivot your data as desired :

```
SELECT 'DeptA' AS "Depatments", SUM(CASE WHEN deptA= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Completed", SUM(CASE WHEN deptA= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Incomplete"
  FROM task
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DeptB', SUM(CASE WHEN deptB= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), SUM(CASE WHEN deptB= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM task
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DeptC', SUM(CASE WHEN deptC= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), SUM(CASE WHEN deptC= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
  FROM task
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DeptD', SUM(CASE WHEN deptD= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), SUM(CASE WHEN deptD= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
  FROM task
```

Comment: Thanks. Like the simplicity. Also works if the datatype of the column is boolean and not integer